# Pear PHP_UML creates XMI... now how do I create a diagram?

Tags: uml, xmi, argouml

I ran PHP_UML against existing PHP code, and have created an XMI file. My goal is to automate turning this XMI file into a visual diagram, i.e. pdf or svg file.

This looked like a good solution, but not sure how to use it properly to get the results I want: http://argouml-graphviz.tigris.org/

Any suggestions/ideas are welcomed